# TypeError passing Series with dtype int to dateutil.relativedelta

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-dateutil

I'm trying to use `dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta` to add an `int` type pandas Series to a `datetime` Series.

```py
df.loc[:,'calc_eli_date'] = (
    datetime.datetime(df['pol_eff_date'])
    + relativedelta(years=df['frt_elig_year'])
)
```

`df['pol_eff_date']` is `datetime64[ns]` type

`df['frt_elig_year']` is `int`

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'int'
```

Comment: I don't see any question. No `?`, no help.

Comment: Please provide sample data, a short explanation of what you are trying to do and what is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dateutil.relativedata.relativedata](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html#dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta) constructor only accepts datetime and integer arguments - not arrays or pandas objects.

Try [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) instead:

```py
df['calc_eli_date'] = (
    df['pol_eff_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['frt_elig_year'], unit='Y')
)
```

Comment: got the same error message using above.                                                             
pol_eff_date is in datetime format eg. 2006-05-03, frt_elig_year is int eg. 15

Comment: sorry error message is:  SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: sorry - updated my answer to drop the datetime.datetime with the same problem. can you post your actual code? if you have a syntax error that's an unrelated problem that we can't debug unless we see your actual implementation. See this post on creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for some really good tips!

Comment: df['calc_eli_date'] = (df['pol_eff_date'] +pd.to_timedelta(df['frst_elig_year'], unit='Y')

Comment: File "<ipython-input-63-e327fe98e96e>", line 1
    df['calc_eli_date'] = (df['pol_eff_date'] +pd.to_timedelta(df['frst_elig_year'], unit='Y')
                                                                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: you're missing a closing paren

Comment: I just realized there is also time how can I select only date?

Comment: check out https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.round.html